# How to parse html in react native

Tags: javascript, html, react-native

So I have html strings in this format:

```
Our society reflects, and is a reflection of, the <del>individual</del><add>person</add> (you and I) , and the <del>individual</del><add>person</add> is a <del>reflection</del><add>manifestation</add> of society (hologram/holon ).
```

And I would like to parse them into nodes like blow:

```
Our society reflects, and is a reflection of, the 
<del>individual</del>
<add>person</add>
(you and I) , and the 
<del>individual</del>
<add>person</add>
is a 
<del>reflection</del>
<add>manifestation</add>
of society (hologram/holon ).
```

I know you can do something like:

```
var element = document.createElement( 'html' );
element.innerHTML = html
nodes = element.childNodes
```

but in react native I got `can't find variable: document` and it seems like I will need a `web-view` to do this. Are there any alternative ways to parse this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no nested nodes nor `<` `>`s in the text proper, then a quick and dirty solution would be to `match` substrings that either start with a tag and end with that tag, or contain no tags:

```js
const str = `Our society reflects, and is a reflection of, the <del>individual</del><add>person</add> (you and I) , and the <del>individual</del><add>person</add> is a <del>reflection</del><add>manifestation</add> of society (hologram/holon ).`;
console.log(str.match(/<(\w+)>[^\<]+<\/\1>|[^<>]+/g))
```

If you want to trim the spaces from the beginning and the end of the substrings, then match non-spaces there too:

```js
const str = `Our society reflects, and is a reflection of, the <del>individual</del><add>person</add> (you and I) , and the <del>individual</del><add>person</add> is a <del>reflection</del><add>manifestation</add> of society (hologram/holon ).`;
console.log(str.match(/<(\w+)>[^\<]+<\/\1>|[^<>\s][^<>]+[^<>\s]/g))
```

But finding a true XML parser to use would be the better general option.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple options here, like you mentioned you could use a WebView like so:

```
<WebView source={{html:"your_html_string"}} />
```

You could also use an npm package like this one:

https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html

Or you could parse the string yourself, and convert it to JSX markup with `<Text />` elements

```
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class del extends Text {
   render() {
      return (
          <Text style={{textDecoration:'line-through'}} ...this.props>{super.render()}</Text>
      )
   }
}

class add extends Text {
   render() {
      return (
          <Text style={{textDecoration:'underline line-through'}} ...this.props>{super.render()}</Text>
      )
   }
}

export default MyScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Text>"Our society reflects, and is a reflection of, the" 
            <del>"individual"</del>
            <add>"person"</add>
            "(you and I) , and the" 
            <del>"individual"</del>
            <add>"person"</add>
            "is a "
            <del>"reflection"</del>
            <add>"manifestation"</add>
            "of society (hologram/holon )."
            </Text>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-render-html

From the docs:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import RenderHtml from 'react-native-render-html';

const source = {
  html: `
<p style='text-align:center;'>
  Hello World!
</p>`
};

export default function App() {
  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
  return (
    <RenderHtml
      contentWidth={width}
      source={source}
    />
  );
}
```